# Error in nonlinear least squeares in R - Logistic and Gompertz curves

Tags: r, nls, non-linear-regression, convergence

I'm working on a model for variable y, in which I intend to use time as an explanatory variable. I've chosen a Gompertz and a logistic curve as candidates, but when I try to estimate the coefficients (using both nls and nls2), I end up getting different errors (singularity or step factor reduced below 'minFactor'). I would really appreciate any help. Here is my code and a deput version of the info object.

I chose the initial values according to the criteria in http://www.metla.fi/silvafennica/full/sf33/sf334327.pdf

```
library(nls2)

> dput(info)
structure(list(y = c(0.308, 0.279, 0.156, 0.214, 0.224, 0.222, 
0.19, 0.139, 0.111, 0.17, 0.155, 0.198, 0.811, 0.688, 0.543, 
0.536, 0.587, 0.765, 0.667, 0.811, 0.587, 0.617, 0.586, 0.633, 
2.231, 2.202, 1.396, 1.442, 1.704, 2.59, 2.304, 3.026, 2.7, 3.275, 
3.349, 3.936, 9.212, 8.773, 6.431, 6.983, 7.169, 9.756, 10.951, 
13.938, 14.378, 18.406, 24.079, 28.462, 51.461, 46.555, 39.116, 
43.982, 41.722), t = 1:53), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -53L))

summary(gomp_nls <- nls2(y ~ alpha*exp(-beta*exp(-gamma*t)), 
                 data = info, 
                 start = list(alpha = 40, beta = 4.9, gamma = 0.02), 
                 algorithm = "default")
        )

summary(logist_nls <- nls2(y ~ alpha/(1+beta*exp(-gamma*t)), 
                          data = info, 
                          start = list(alpha = 40, beta = 128, gamma = 0.02), 
                          algorithm = "default"))
        )
```

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Those are models for sigmoid growth.  Your data shows no sign of being sigmoid.  Try fitting a simple exponential growth model instead.

Comment: Hi, in this dataset y is migrants to a country, so it can't be exponential, it must reach a saturation point

Comment: Statistics aren't magic.  If your data show no sign of a saturation point, the model won't be able to find it.  (This discussion belongs on the stats.stackexchange.com site, not the programming site.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"default"` algorithm for `nls2` is to use `nls`.  You want to specify `"brute-force"` or one of the other algorithms for finding an initial value.  The starting value should be a data frame of two rows such that it will fill in the hypercube so defined with potential starting values.

It will then evaluate the residual sum of squares at each of those starting values and return the starting values at which the formula gives the least sum of squares.

If you find that the result returned by `nls2` is at the boundary of the region you defined then enlarge the region and try again.  (You might not need this step if the starting value returned are good enough anyways.)

Finally run `nls` with the starting values you found.

```
library(nls2)

## 1

fo1 <- y ~ alpha*exp(-beta*exp(-gamma*t))
st1 <- data.frame(alpha = c(10, 100), beta = c(1, 100), gamma = c(0.01, 0.20))
fm1.0 <- nls2(fo1, data = info, start = st1, algorithm = "brute-force")

fm1 <- nls(fo1, data = info, start = coef(fm1.0))

## 2

fo2 <- y ~ alpha/(1+beta*exp(-gamma*t))
st2 <- data.frame(alpha = c(10, 1000), beta = c(1, 10000), gamma = c(0.01, 0.20))
fm2.0 <- nls2(fo2, data = info, start = st2, algorithm = "brute-force")

fm2 <- nls(fo2, data = info, start = coef(fm2.0))

# plot both fits

plot(y ~ t, info)
lines(fitted(fm1) ~ t, info, col = "blue")
lines(fitted(fm2) ~ t, info, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

Note that for the data shown these two 2-parameter exponential models fit reasonably well so if you are only interested in the range where it rises exponentially then these could be alternatives to consider.  (The first one below is better because the coefficients are more similar to each other. The second one may have scaling problems.)

```
fm3 <- nls(y ~ a * exp(b/t), info, start = c(a = 1, b = 1))
fm4 <- nls(y ~ a * t^b, info, start = c(a = .001, b = 6))
```